# MSSQL guid to string

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, laravel-5.1, php-7

I'm using Laravel 5.1 on Ubuntu PHP5.6 and the GUID to string conversion is working just fine.  However on my development environment in PHP 7 it's pritining out like how it used to when I had to use the old mssql driver that came with php.

So all my string comparisons are failing on 7 for GUID's saved in mysql.

My gut says that some PDO setting that's not being set correctly.  The query in question is using the DB class to fetch data through a raw sql.  I think Eloquent is rendering correctly, I've not seen this problem before and I've been using it throughout (this is an older code base before I leaned additional tricks I currently use to work with this database)

Any ideas where I can start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the particular set of credentials and set up for the software that was causing the byte problem.  I was logging in fine but changing the connection string fixed the problem.